# How to get list of sip peers from endpoints with ari-py

Tags: python, asterisk, asterisk-ari

It is not clear how to get list of sip peers from ari/endpoints with this library.

Examples in repository show actions with channels and bridges but not with endpoints.

The JSON response is available via localhost:8088/ari/endpoints/SIP with browser or wscat.

How to get it via ari client ?

```
import ari
SERVER_ADDR = "http://localhost:8088/"
USER = "user"
PWD = "pwd"
client = ari.connect(SERVER_ADDR, USER, PWD)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To list the endpoints, you can use:

```
client.endpoints.list()
```

To list the SIP endpoints, you can use:

```
client.endpoints.listByTech(tech='SIP')
```

The `ari-py` client is built from the OpenAPI spec returned by Asterisk. There is no other documentation than the OpenAPI spec. You can read the OpenAPI spec [with SwaggerUI](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Using+Swagger+to+Drive+ARI).

You can also read the OpenAPI spec directly in text [on Github](https://github.com/asterisk/asterisk/tree/master/rest-api/api-docs) for example. The name of the methods of the `ari-py` client are the same as the `nickname` of the OpenAPI spec operations, which unfortunately is not shown in SwaggerUI at http://ari.asterisk.org.